# what does the astericks mean at end of ls -l -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root size date file*

Tags: linux, centos

Every file or link in my CentOS `/usr/bin` has an astericks at the end of it. None of them do on my local osX server. What does this mean? I have searched google and here specifically with no luck.

`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root       107104 Nov 11  2010 zipcloak*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         2953 Oct 10  2008 zipgrep*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root       159928 Nov 11  2010 zipinfo*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        98584 Nov 11  2010 zipnote*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root       102680 Nov 11  2010 zipsplit*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         1731 May 27  2013 zless*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         2605 May 27  2013 zmore*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         5246 May 27  2013 znew*`

Comment: Related: [What are = and | in the output of “ls -F”?](http://askubuntu.com/q/250864/74792) from Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an indicator showing that the files are *executable*. From the documentation for ls, section ["General output formatting"](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html) (`info coreutils 'general output formatting'`):

> ```
> ‘-F’
> ‘--classify’
> ‘--indicator-style=classify’
>     Append a character to each file name indicating the file type.
>     Also, for regular files that are executable, append ‘*’.
> ```

Your system probably has an alias for `ls` which is expanded to `ls -F`.

The [**ls**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) from Mac OS X has this option too, but you'll have you use it explicitly i.e. run `ls -F`.

> ```
> -F  Display a slash (`/') immediately after each pathname that is a
>     directory, an asterisk (`*') after each that is executable, an
>     at sign (`@') after each symbolic link, an equals sign (`=') after
>     each socket, a percent sign (`%') after each whiteout, and a
>     vertical bar (`|') after each that is a FIFO.
> ```

Comment: yup. there are the astericks when I run ls -F on the mac. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

GNU `ls` offers the option `-F` which causes file names to be suffixed with certain characters indicating the type of file:

```
   -F, --classify
          append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
```

where `*` signifies an executable file, `/` signifies a directory, `=` signifies a socket, etc.  It's likely that the listing command you're using on your CentOS box is aliased to something like `/bin/ls -lF`.  If you type `/bin/ls -l /usr/bin` on your CentOS box, then the `*` will disappear.

Try typing `ls -lF` on your OSX server and see if that works.  Note that the `ls` that comes with OSX is **not** GNU `ls`; it is OpenBSD `ls`, which might not support `-F` (I'm not sure).  Type `man ls` on OSX to see what options it supports.  (You can also install GNU `fileutils` on OSX using `macports`.)

Comment: If I'm not mistaking Mac OS X got its a lot of its programs including **ls** from FreeBSD, not OpenBSD. Also **Fileutils**, Shellutils, and Textutils have been combined into the **GNU Coreutils** package.

Comment: Good points.  It has been 3 years since I had to think about this on my current Mac.  You may be entirely correct.

Comment: It looks like the macport is named [**coreutils**](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/coreutils/Portfile) too, not just the upstream project.